# Создание iframe с помощью js и загрузкой контента по ссылке в него

Tags: javascript, iframe

Пусть я попадаю на страницу, на которой работает мой `js-скрипт`(подключен через greasemonkey). С помощью него на странице создаю элемент `iframe`:

```
var el = document.createElement("iframe");
el.id = "iframe";
el.style.width = "1000px";
el.style.height = "800px";
el.src = HrefLinkOnParentPage;
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Естественно, возникла проблема, заключающаяся в том, что пространство имен `js` совпадает у `parent-страницы` и `child-страницы`. Из-за этого рекурсивно создаются фреймы в фреймах.

Есть какой-нибудь способ определить, что страница является `child` или `parent`? Т.е. после создания фрейма в первый раз надо определить, что она является фреймом главной страницы и остановить выполнение скрипта на ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откопал функцию: `window.frameElement`, которая возвращает null если этот документ не встроен в другой, или иначе ссылку на элемент, в который он встроен:

```
var frameEl = window.frameElement;
if (frameEl==null) alert("main frame"); else alert("embedded frame");
```

С помощью этого можно отличить встроенный фрейм от главного.